# How to Install Basemap for Mac Pycharm

Tags: python

I have searched many places and cannot find a simple guide for installing Basemap via Pycharm for Mac. I already have geos and proj installed. Please help

Answer (score 2):

This is addressed in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13262
and https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/198

Typing `conda install basemap` at the command line should suffice.

Consider listing your project requirements in a conda `environments.yml` file, for convenient reference via pycharm.